# How to hide some columns from the output result?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *, 
       @f1 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 0 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE @f1
                   END f1,
       @f2 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND diff >= 10
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE @f2
                   END f2,
       @f3 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1
                   THEN @f3 + 10
                   ELSE 0
                   END f3,
       CASE WHEN @f3 > 0 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN bsp * 10 - @f3
                   ELSE @f3
                   END 'profit/loss',
       CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN (@f1 := 1) + (@f2 := 0) + (@f3 := 0)
                   ELSE 0
                   END f4
FROM test, ( SELECT @f1 := 0, @f2 := 0, @f3 := 0 ) vars
ORDER BY datec;
```

I have a table called test and I want to use a select statement to create and calculate profit/loss column by using some conditions (Code is already in the fiddle). I want to hide the columns **`(@f1 :=0, @f2 :=0, @f3 :=0, f1, f2, f3, f4)`** from the output result. Output result columns that I want it **`(sf_name, finish_position, official_rating, datec, bsp, diff, profit/loss)`**.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a07e866e30b5543dc98e2b4954893b04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a subquery then select the columns you want in the main query.

```
SELECT sf_name, finish_position, official_rating, datec, bsp, diff, `profit/loss`
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           @f1 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 0 AND finish_position = 1
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE @f1
                       END f1,
           @f2 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND diff >= 10
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE @f2
                       END f2,
           @f3 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1
                       THEN @f3 + 10
                       ELSE 0
                       END f3,
           CASE WHEN @f3 > 0 AND finish_position = 1
                       THEN bsp * 10 - @f3
                       ELSE @f3
                       END 'profit/loss',
           CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1 AND finish_position = 1
                       THEN (@f1 := 1) + (@f2 := 0) + (@f3 := 0)
                       ELSE 0
                       END f4
    FROM test, ( SELECT @f1 := 0, @f2 := 0, @f3 := 0 ) vars
) AS x
ORDER BY datec;
```